# missing moveit files

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, buiding-errors

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I'm new to ROS and recently went through the ROS-I training. I'm trying to keep going with the training exercises but I ran into a strange build issue when I moved Descartes packages into my workspace.

for reference the training material I'm referring to https://industrial-training-master.readthedocs.io/en/melodic/

My workspace builds and everything is great until exercise 4.1 and I add the Descartes packages in. When I try and build now I get the following error.

```
Errors     << ur5_demo_descartes:make /home/rosindustrial2/catkin_ws/logs/ur5_demo_descartes/build.make.011.log
In file included from /home/rosindustrial2/catkin_ws/src/ur5_demo_descartes/src/ur_moveit_plugin.cpp:87:0:
/home/rosindustrial2/catkin_ws/src/ur5_demo_descartes/include/ur5_demo_descartes/ur_moveit_plugin.h:97:10: fatal error: moveit/kdl_kinematics_plugin/chainiksolver_pos_nr_jl_mimic.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <moveit/kdl_kinematics_plugin/chainiksolver_pos_nr_jl_mimic.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ur5_demo_descartes.dir/src/ur_moveit_plugin.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /home/rosindustrial2/catkin_ws/src/ur5_demo_descartes/include/ur5_demo_descartes/ur5_robot_model.h:16:0,
                 from /home/rosindustrial2/catkin_ws/src/ur5_demo_descartes/src/plugin_init.cpp:8:
/home/rosindustrial2/catkin_ws/src/ur5_demo_descartes/include/ur5_demo_descartes/ur_moveit_plugin.h:97:10: fatal error: moveit/kdl_kinematics_plugin/chainiksolver_pos_nr_jl_mimic.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <moveit/kdl_kinematics_plugin/chainiksolver_pos_nr_jl_mimic.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/rosindustrial2/catkin_ws/src/ur5_demo_descartes/include/ur5_demo_descartes/ur5_robot_model.h:16:0,
                 from /home/rosindustrial2/catkin_ws/src/ur5_demo_descartes/src/ur5_robot_model.cpp:8:
/home/rosindustrial2/catkin_ws/src/ur5_demo_descartes/include/ur5_demo_descartes/ur_moveit_plugin.h:97:10: fatal error: moveit/kdl_kinematics_plugin/chainiksolver_pos_nr_jl_mimic.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <moveit/kdl_kinematics_plugin/chainiksolver_pos_nr_jl_mimic.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ur5_demo_descartes.dir/src/plugin_init.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ur5_demo_descartes.dir/src/ur5_robot_model.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ur5_demo_descartes.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
cd /home/rosindustrial2/catkin_ws/build/ur5_demo_descartes; catkin build --get-env ur5_demo_descartes | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=6,7 -j; cd -
```

It seems like I'm missing a move it file somewhere but I've tried to uninstall and reinstall moveit but no success. We have another identical laptop that a coworker used in the training and he does not have this issue. I did some looking and using the "find" command I can find the file this error says is missing in the same place on my computer as his computer.

any thoughts on whats wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318599/missing-moveit-files/) by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue has been solved.

https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/403

---

Originally posted by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) with karma: 28 on 2019-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0